# Does the box.com API have picker control like Google Picker

Tags: box-api

We need to integrate Box API functions into our web app. While working with Google Drive we were using Google Picker as GUI for selecting file. Has the box.com API something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Ho tombom,

You may want to try filepicker.io.  They built a picker tool that connects to the Box API for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Box API tools just provide the backend interface to the the information necessary to build an interface, leaving the interface elements up to the application to handle.

If you're working on a web interface a common choice is http://www.jstree.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you are using, Box has started to provide example folder-pickers.  Check out the SDK pages